# Controlling the "Oops! Chrome could not find ... " page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When you type in an invalid address, Chrome displays a grey page that says "Oops! Google Chrome could not find X. Did you mean Y?"

Because this is not an HTTP page but rather one of the browser's built-in things, I can't put a content script in it and can't control it, so my extension is frozen until the user manually goes to another page.

Since the extension is supposed to be able to control the browser on its own, it's very important that anytime this page opens, it automatically goes back to a page I *do* have content script access to, and then displays a message instead.

Is this impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onErrorOccurred) to detect such errors, and redirect to a different page if you want. Unless you've got an extremely good reason to do so, I strongly **recommend against** implementing such a feature, because it might break the user's expectations of how the browser behaves.

Nevertheless, sample code:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred(function(details) {
    if (details.frameId === 0) {
        // Main frame
        chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL('error.html?error=' + encodeURIComponent(details.error))
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I need it because it's for a voice control extension. When the user says "Go to X.com", if it mishears him, it brings up that Oops page and the voice control would cease to work. For a paraplegic user, the voice control cannot stop at any time or someone has to come start it up again for them. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @Aerovistae Have you considered using a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) with a [browser action button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)?

Comment: @Aerovistae The "Oops not found" is not the only page where content scripts are disabled, by the way. Other pages include (but not limited to): chrome:, about:, chrome-extension:. data:, blob:, file: (when "allow access to file URLs" is disabled) and any page in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: Looks like it's now `chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener`

Answer (score 1):

According to **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html)** the only pages an extension can override are:

- The bookmarks manager
- The history
- The new-tab

So, an extension can't change/contol/affect the behaviour of the browser regarding the "Oops!..." page.