# Chrome extension to reload page on load error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Because [it isn't possible to use Greasemonkey for this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23722801/492130), I want to write a Chrome extension that will reload a page if it initially failed to load.

I know how to write a Chrome extension, I've already injected scripts and figured out how to communicate with pages, so I have basic knowledge of how tabs work and how to build my manifest.

What events am I looking for and how can I make it work for both GET and POST requests?

Comment: Would be great if you let us be part of your solution ;-)  I'm looking for the same solution. Do you implemented this hack in a plugin?

Comment: @Smoki Sorry, but this was a long time ago and I don't have the code any more.

Comment: @Smoki if you're looking for a Chrome extension that will continually retry loading a page that has failed to load, I just posted an answer with such an extension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66238031/3442232

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onErrorOccurred) or [`chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onErrorOccurred) to detect navigation errors. These APIs cannot be used in a content script, so you have to add a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) to your extension.

I recommend to use the `webNavigation` API because these can also be used with event pages (unlike the `webRequest` API). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515560/controlling-the-oops-chrome-could-not-find-page/20516620#20516620) is an example, use [`chrome.tabs.reload`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload) instead of `chrome.tabs.update` to get what you want.

Comment: I got to the point where I injected a content script and reloaded if the injection failed... it was a very dirty hack. This is the answer I'm looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for a Chrome extension that will continually retry loading a page that has failed to load, the [Error Page Enhanced](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/error-page-enhanced/phnaagakdgflhjpekoiklejdgadnlbgc/) Chrome extension has this as part of its primary functionality.